# Salesforce Android home screen widget

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, android

I would like to create an Android home screen widget that displays a report chart coming from Salesforce.
I've been looking at the widgets a bit and it seems there are only a limited number of layouts and views possible.
I don't see how to achieve this.

Any ideas if this is possible and how to go about it?